# Calling a function inside JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the difference between calling functions in JSX in the following alternative ways (using React Hooks here). For function `equals`:

```
const equals = () =>  {
    //Actual code instructs things to do here
}
```

Alternatives:

```
<button id="equals" onClick={() => equals()}>=</button>
```

and

```
<button id="equals" onClick={equals}>=</button>
```

and

```
<button id="equals" onClick={equals()}>=</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button id="equals" onClick={() => equals()}>=</button>
```

The above method uses an anonymous function that calls `equals`. This is done to prevent infinite re-rendering in react.`() => {}` is an example of an anonymous function.

```
<button id="equals" onClick={equals}>=</button>
```

The code above calls the equals method directly, calling its instance once. This can also be used in react to prevent infinite re-rendering.

```
<button id="equals" onClick={equals()}>=</button>
```

This last example should not be used. It will trigger the `equals` function every render, and create an infinite loop in react.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

THe first two options are equivalent

```
onClick={() => callback()}
```

Is the same as

```
onClick={callback}
```

We usually wrap the handler on another function when passing aditional arguments

```
onClick={e => callback(e, 'foo')}
```

The third way is the immediate execution of the handler

```
const createHandler = () => e => console.log(e)

onClick={createHandler()} // e => console.log(e)
```